# What are the different ways of creating elements

Tags: javascript, dom, element

Say I want to overwrite `form.elements` on all forms (current and future).

#### Motivation

[This question on polyfilling `RadioNodeList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941984/how-to-polyfill-radionodelist) could be solved by intercepting all `form` elements and manually writing an own getter for the `elements` property on them.

#### How do I intercept?

Apart from the below what other ways are there of creating (form) elements that I need to intercept

- `document.createElement`
- `document.createElementNS`
- `Node.importNode`
- `Node.cloneNode`
- `DOMImplementation.createDocument` (Maybe, depends how effective overwriting `Document.prototype.createElement`/`NS` is)

#### What are the other downsides?

Seperate question, ignoring the performance hits what good reasons are there for not intercepting node creation?

Comment: What is a good reason for intercepting it?

Comment: what to do about `.innerHTML` ?

Comment: @AbePetrillo updated motivation

Comment: @Raynos for the innerHTML you could set a watcher.

Comment: Not just `innerHTML`, also `outerHTML`, and `insertAdjacentHTML` - defined by [DOM Parsing](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interception of the form elements can be done with a function that parses the nodes by tag name searching for form if a specific event or attribute is not set like you have than you would have to set it else it is an already intercepted form.

The second alternative is to override the `createElement` on `Element` and on `document` for the new elements to come to be parsed by the above mentioned function.

The bad part is that for older IE versions you would have to write a separate HTC file to make the Element's behavior as you wish.

Hope this helps, even if it is a lot of info and no code ( it is a pretty nasty code ).

EDIT:

In other words you could create a Overridden DOM class for Cross-Browser usage ( or at least this is what i am doing for the las 4 months ), where you take all the special behaviors and treat them for special reasons.

Comment: how do you deal with new nodes not having the behaviour. And how do you gaurd againts `innerHTML` and `document.write` etc

Comment: either you create them using the newly overridden createElement either you set a watcher on innerHTML or by manualy appending a call to the form parser function every time you make a change. If you do it by ajax just call it at the start of the update handler function.

Comment: @Raynos document.write can be overridden also to call your function.

Comment: You mention "overridden DOM class for cross-browser usage". Is it DOM compliant? Does it fix browser bugs? Is it open source? Is it similar to [DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) ?

Comment: @Raynos Yes, Yes, Not yet, I'll take a closer look to DOM-shim but at first sight is similar.

Comment: I will bribe you with SO rep if you open source and reference it o/

Comment: @Raynos :)) nice but i can't accept it. First i want to remodel it and then i will publish it. I want to be a serious thing even though i already am using it in some nasty ajax-based web-apps. But when finished you'll be the first to know. ;)