# How do I access the RadioNodeList interface on a Fieldset

Tags: javascript, radiobuttonlist

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList)

*"The RadioNodeList interface represents a collection of radio elements in a form or a **fieldset** element."*

But in the [example on the value property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList/value) a form element is used.

I have not been able to figure out how to access the interface on a fieldset.

[Attempt on codepen](https://codepen.io/steffendyhr-nielsen/pen/bGMeOMW)

HTML:

```
<form id="radioNodeList_form">
  <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">Blue</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="red">Red</label>
</form>


<fieldset id="radioNodeList_fieldset">
  <label><input type="radio" name="color_" value="blue">Blue</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="color_" value="red">Red</label>
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
const form = document.getElementById('radioNodeList_form');

let radios = form.elements['color'];

console.log(radios);

radios.value = 'red';


const fieldset = document.getElementById('radioNodeList_fieldset');

radios = fieldset.querySelectorAll('input');

console.log(radios);
```

Help would be appreciated. Thx ;)

Comment: Your codepen link is broken. Anyway, there is a `HTMLFieldsetElement.elements` readonly property that returns a list of all controls in the `<fieldset>` element, similar to `HTMLFormElement.elements`. That's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thx...  I'll fix the link and check your proposal

Comment: HTMLFieldsetElement.elements returns a HTMLCollection object and setting value = "red" will just add the property to the collection. I need access to the underlying RadioNodeList object for the value property to work on the radio buttons as per the documentation

Comment: There is an inconsistency with regard to access of radio buttons in HTML. Does this answer your question? [How to get value of selected radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Comment: Nope, but thx..  I wan't access to the RadioNodeList for consistent, clean code. I like the form example from MDN, and currently I'll just stick with a form, but I would prefer a Fieldset

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941984/how-to-polyfill-radionodelist

Answer (score 0):

I achieved getting the RadioNodeList by accessing the fieldset form first.

```
const fieldset = document.querySelector('fieldset [id=radioNodeList_fieldset]')
const form = fieldset.form;
const nodeList = form.elements['color_'];
```

then you can get value from the `nodeList`

`nodeList.value`

```
const nodeList = document
  .querySelector('fieldset [id=radioNodeList_fieldset]')
  .form.elements['color_'];
const value = nodeList.value;
```

I haven't find a better way to access a `fieldset` radio node list

Comment: Your code throws this exception: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'form')  https://codepen.io/steffendyhr-nielsen/pen/bGMeOMW